# Have "Sapir-Whorf sensitivity" and "differential neuroplasticity" been considered so far?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, linguistics, plasticity

I watched the movie "Arrival" today and came to define the concept of "Sapir-Whorf sensitivity" as the measure of to what extent is the way of thinking of somebody influenced by the languages they know. As this is an instance of neuroplasticity, one may think that the latter varies across the brain, which leads to the concept of "differential neuroplasticy". That way, intelligence as the ability to learn could be categorized as a brain map of this differential neuroplasticity through the diverse functional areas of the brain. This would explain why different persons can be very intelligent though in different ways.

Have such concepts been studied before?

Comment: Your theory doesn't make logical sense to me, in particular "As this is an instance of neuroplasticity, one may think that the latter varies across the brain".

Comment: Sapir-Whorf sensitivity only has to do with language, but of course language is not the only cognitive function the brain allows. Shoud I have written "peculiar example" instead of "instance"?